# Cannot use a MySQL UDF function

Tags: mysql, function, user-defined-functions

I have loaded an UDF function into MySQL (without having selected any particular DB). It used to work well during my session but now I get the error "ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION currentdatabase.myfunction does not exist" when I try to use the function with the following sql statement :

```
select myfunction('aaa');
```

I then tried to drop the function and I got the same error code :

```
mysql> drop function myfunction;
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION database.myfunction does not exist
```

if a DB is selected.

Another error code otherwise :

```
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
```

So I decided to specify again the function and I got the following error code :

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunction RETURNS INT SONAME 'myfunction.so';
ERROR 1125 (HY000): Function 'myfunction' already exists
```

My question is: how to use again my function ?

Thanks in advance.

Note: there is no space problem like ("select myfunction ('aaa');") as reported on several other websites.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I believe the problem is that we (at least I did) remove the shared .so library before dropping the function or while mysqld was still running. Don't know how to solve this, someone? `SELECT * FROM mysql.func` lists the function I want to use.

Answer (score 6):

I recently encountered this issue my self and I put together a quick blog post about it:

> When [installing a UDF recently](https://github.com/treffynnon/lib_mysqludf_ssdeep) I got an
>   annoying error message, which didn't seem to want to go away. Deleting
>   the function before attempting to remove it did not work so I used the
>   following set of escalating commands to attempt to get it to
>   install.
>
> But back to the error for a moment:
>
> ```
> bash > mysql -u user -p < installdb.sql
> Enter password:
> ERROR 1125 (HY000) at line 7: Function 'lib_mysqludf_ssdeep_info' already exists
> ```
>
> This can be
>   solved really simply with the following options:
>
> 1. Attempt
>      to delete the function and then reinstall it
> 2. Delete the
>      function row from the mysql.func table and then reinstall it
> 3. Stop the MySQL server (after trying option 2), start it again and
>      then reinstall it

From my testing you do not need to have backups of your binary database files as @jmcejuela suggests in his answer.

Source: http://simonholywell.com/post/2012/01/mysql-udf-install-error-function-already-exists.html

Comment: +1 2. deleting the function row from mysql.func, restarting the server, and then re-creating the function worked for me.

Comment: This is not working for me, seems like my percona xtradb cluster makes this a bit more complicated

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem comes from removing the .so library before dropping the function/s. The server still believes it has the functions since they appear in `SELECT * FROM mysql.func` but of course calling these functions fail. Somehow `DROP` doesn't simply remove entries in this table but also checks whether the libraries are found which makes this fail. `CREATE` supposedly just check first the `func` table which makes this fail...

The solution is to restore the func table (func.MYI, func.MYD, func.frm files under your mysql's data/mysql) to the point everything matches.

Luckily I had a backup of these files. Otherwise you will have to backup them from a new mysql installation (you could simply install locally a new server not to remove your current one)

Bottom line: do not remove the .so libraries before dropping the functions.

Answer (score -1):

Got some of these errors when swapping out (not dropping) the .so library before dropping the function(s).

Restarting the server eliminated the error messages, whether the functions were successfully dropped or not. Mysqld just looked at the mysql.func table and loaded functions from the (new) .so. I know restarting the server is not always an option, but if it is, it's fast and complete.